# Using Three20 Library

Tags: iphone, ipad, three20

I'm a baby iOS developer.
I really need help.

I want to use three20 library in my project and I add this library correctly.
but when I want to used it, I got a error.

for example when I write this line on top of my classes :

```
"#import "Three20/Three20.h"
```

I got this error:

```
Three20/Three20.h:No such file or directory
```

What hell is it? What can I do? I really need help as soon as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Copy the actual error messages from Xcode and paste them here

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem :).

Thanks to this site:

http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project

Comment: Accept your answer and you will get more rep.